# Present a viewcontroller modally

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I'm trying to present a viewcontroller modally on my landscape ONLY iOS app. I've looked at and tried `modalPresentationStyle`, but according to the documentations all of these styles show as full screen in a horizontally compact environment, which results in a full screen for me. The `preferredContentSize` does not work for me either.

I'm trying to present it [similar to this gif](https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/blob/master/Screenshots/example.gif)

Comment: You can just use custom view for this, dont really need to make new viewcontroller

Comment: You can show custom UIView instead of UIViewController and grey UIView for background.

Comment: I would like to use a view, but my view ended up being a lot of logic. It is similar to the gif but it is a 2d array in a collectionview

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I ended up checking the source code of the gif that i linked. In this scenario they used a new window on top of the other window, which gives me everything I need. The beauty is in the reusability and independence of the viewcontroller i am showing it in, i.e. not attached to any view and not a child viewcontroller etc.

So to sum up: Make another `UIWindow` with `UIWindowLevelAlert` on top of the main window.

Answer (score -1):

Try this way:

Create some UIView and set it's hidden property = true

if you need any UIView, just set it's hidden property = false.

Or

Anytime you need any View. You just need to create that View by code and then addSubView.
When your work done, just remove that view from parent's subview